# Get notified when execution context is changed or created

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver, chromium

I am injecting bunch of javascript code to a website by means of selenium webdriver (over chromedriver).

While the method i use works most of the time, it fails when an iframe is loaded or page is reloaded by website's javascript code.

I can trace the problem from the chromedriver's log. 
For example:

```
[6.203][DEBUG]: DEVTOOLS EVENT Runtime.executionContextDestroyed {
   "executionContextId": 1
}
[6.203][DEBUG]: DEVTOOLS EVENT Runtime.executionContextsCleared {

}
[6.203][DEBUG]: DEVTOOLS EVENT Runtime.executionContextCreated {
   "context": {
      "auxData": {
         "frameId": "274.1",
         "isDefault": true
      },
      "id": 5,
      "name": "",
      "origin": "https://<some url>"
   }
}
```

When i see `executionContextDestroyed` i know that, most probably my injected scripts are destroyed too. I have tried bunch of options like `switch_to.default_content()` or `switch_to.parent_frame` but they didn't help, as there is nothing to do in case of reload but re-inject the scripts.

My question is, is there a way to hook into `executionContextCreated` events, so i can inject my scripts/functions into the context again and again.